# I created a dice cube model using a tutorial and i would like to expoert the subdivision holes as properties to unity3d. how can i do it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, properties, blender

This is the tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrzvb8HJV-8&t=2s

This is the model in my blender:

[image: dice model in blender]

in the video tutorial it's on minute 9:31 Extrude Faces Along Normals and then when you press the I key you can extrude the holes for example:

[image: extrude]

I want to be able to control this extrude of each hole in unity3d in the inspector. to change the scale/extrude of each hole just like in the video.

so when I export the model to unity3d it will have also each hole as object or as it should be so I can control each hole scale and other properties.

this is how the dice cube looks like in unity3d after imported it to unity. in the hierarchy I have the cube object and a light. but I want to have also the holes each hole as object when importing it to unity.

the dice cube model in unity3d:

[image: the dice model in unity3d]

Comment: Unity is not a and not meant to be a 3D modelling software ;) For sure you could somehow write a generative component script that basically generates according mesh based on your input ... but then again until you implement that you could as well load the mesh in any 3D modelling software and adjust it there .. Once you imported the mesh into Unity it isn't aware of any subdivide modifier anymore .. only the resulting vertices and triangles - your Blender export/import already applies this and you don't know it on Unity side